# Python: Efficiently iterating over a multidimensional list

Tags: python, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm using for-loops to iterate over two-dimensional list:

```
def itr(lpic, lH, lW, x, y):
    '''lpic=2D-Array; lH=Row_count; lW=Column_count;'''
    stack = []
    range_x = range(x-1, x+2)
    range_y = range(y-1, y+2)
    append = stack.append
    for i in range_x:
                if 0<=i<lH:#i is a valid index *Updated
                    for j in range_y:
                        if (0<=j<lW) and (lpic[i][j]=="0"):
                            lpic[i][j] = "1"
                            append([i, j])
    return stack
```

I'd like to know if there is a better way to do the same with Python2.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two simple optimizations for your code:

1. Use `xrange` instead for `range`. This will prevent from generation two temporary lists.
2. Use `min` and `max` in parameters for `xrange` to omit 'if' in outer loop. So you code will look like that:

```py
def itr(lpic, lH, lW, x, y):
    '''lpic=2D-Array; lH=Row_count; lW=Column_count;'''
    stack = []
    range_x = xrange(max(0,x-1), min(lH,x+2))
    range_y = xrange(max(0,y-1), min(lW,y+2))
    append = stack.append
    for i in range_x:
      for j in range_y:
          if lpic[i][j]=="0":
              lpic[i][j] = "1"
              append([i, j])
    return stack
```

This will slightly increase performance.

Comment: I heard xrange is deprecated in Python3.

Comment: @Sathvik: `range` in Python3 behaves like `xrange` in Python2. `list(range(...))` is the Python3 equivalent of `range` in Python2. Consequently, the *name* `xrange` has been removed from Python3, but not the behavior.

Answer (score 5):

**Not really.** In Python 2.6 if you wanted to compact your code a little, you could use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to turn it into a single `for` loop, but the general efficiency wouldn't change at all - you'd still have `N*M` iterations of the loop.

```
import itertools

def itr(lpic, lH, lW, x, y):
    '''lpic=2D-Array; lH=Row_count; lW=Column_count;'''
    stack = []
    range_x = range(x-1, x+2)
    range_y = range(y-1, y+2)
    append = stack.append
    for i,j in itertools.product(range_x, range_y):
        if 0 <= i < lh and 0 <= j < lW and lpic[i][j]=="0":
            lpic[i][j] = "1"
            append([i, j])
    return stack
```

Comment: `itertools.product` is in 2.6+.

Comment: @Avaris - true. :) Well then, the first sentence stands. :)

Comment: Right :). Also, maybe you can shorten the if conditions to: `0<=i<lH and 0<=j<lW and lpic[i][j]=="0"`.